# Is using CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls in conjunction with AddOwnedForm/RemovedOwnForm safe?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I would like to have a form which is associated with the application's main UI thread own several other forms which each have their own thread (each form is associated with a piece of hardware, and I would like updates to be processed on those forms even if the main form is busy for a second or so).  The primary desired purpose of ownership is to maintain the window stacking behavior (owned forms stay above the owner in Z order, but are not forced above the windows of other applications).

Many questions on SO asked how to do this, and answers suggested that it may be possible to set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to false briefly when changing ownership, but were hedged with caveats indicating the people suggesting that approach didn't know whether it was really safe.

I can see at least two possible issues with the approaches:

- Changing the `Owner` of a form will effectively call `AddOwnedForm` and/or `RemoveOwnedForm` on its owner.  I would not expect that setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to false would make that method thread-safe.  If multiple forms bound to different threads are simultaneously shown or hidden, that could be a problem.  I would expect that using something like `NewOwner.Invoke(() => NewOwner.AddOwnedForm(this))` would ease that problem.
- From what I can tell, `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` is a global property.  As such, I would be worried about the possibility that if two threads simultaneously set it false, one thread might set it to true while the other thread still needs it to be false.  Having the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` cleared and re-set as part of the method passed to the cross-thread `Invoke` would seem like it might solve the problem if the main UI thread is the only one that ever writes to that property, but I don't know if there might be any writes to that property "hidden" in any of the .NET UI code.

At the moment the application in question is intended for internal use only.  On the other hand, it would be nice to have an approach which could be considered robust enough for production code.  Have there been any new discoveries in this regard since the other responses were written?  Would the suggested approaches (having ownership acquisition/release handled in the main thread) be adequate to make things robust?

PS--It would be even nicer if there were some way I could have child MDI windows use other threads; conceptually there's no reason why that couldn't be possible (the only effects a and parent MDI window should have on each other would be either when the child is added or removed from the parent's list of child windows (situation similar to owned windows), or when the child window is moved and exposes some of the parent (which is pretty much like the situation where some other application's window is moved and exposes the parent--obviously a situation WinForms has deal with routinely).

Comment: Having threads interacting with the hardware deal with the hardware, and having a single UI thread deal with the UI still seems very appealing here. Is there a specific reason that you want to have hardware and forms tied together?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Some of the buttons on the main form will trigger actions which may take a noticeable fraction of a second to complete.  Having the main form thread handle them would be easier than using a worker thread, but I don't want to have all the other forms freeze when a button is clicked in the main form, especially since I may be interested in seeing the relative timing of how the different pieces of hardware react to the events triggered by the main form code.